# Javascript promises: Explain the output

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(this, "hello"), 5000);
}).then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(this, value+"1"), 5000);
    }).then(function(val){
        console.log(val);
    });
}).then(function(value){
    console.log("last one is " +value);
});
```

The output of the above code is:

`//hello`

`//hello1`

`//last one is undefined`

From my understanding, the `then` function gets the return value of the previous function as an argument. And if a promise is returned, then `then` will receive the resolved value of the promise.

Here, I introduced `then` of the promise itself. This made the console to print `last one is undefined`.

If I try to run the following code:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(this, "hello"), 5000);
}).then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(this, value+"1"), 5000);
    });
}).then(function(value){
    console.log("last one is " +value);
});
```

The output is:

`//hello`

`//last one is hello1`

Comment: Your not returning anything from your second `then` with the console.log,.. just do `return val;` after the console.log.

Comment: @Keith Is there an article where I can read a better explanation of what is passed to the promises and how they run? I am trying to implement my own Promise library.

Comment: `I am trying to implement my own Promise library.`, oh that's not going to be trivial, any reason your wanting to do this?.  Promise's are now built into browsers & node.js.  But if you still want to do it, the specification can be found here -> https://promisesaplus.com/  Even the people who wrote jQuery got it wrong when they implemented it, so there are lots of gotcha's.

Comment: To be better at js :)